# Checking if Any.Type conforms to a protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I like to check if given value of `Any.Type` conforms to a protocol in Swift.  It seems that `@objc` based protocol can be checked by calling `class_conformsToProtocol()`, but I do not have a good idea how to check that with pure swift protocol.

```
// ObjC

@objc protocol MyObjcProtocol {
}

class MyObjcClass: NSObject, MyObjcProtocol {
}

class_conformsToProtocol(MyObjcClass.self, MyObjcProtocol.self) // true

// Swift

protocol MySwiftProtocol: AnyObject {
}

class MySwiftClass: MySwiftProtocol {
}

class_conformsToProtocol(MySwiftClass.self, MySwiftProtocol.self) // error
```

If it is the case of an instance, I can check with `if let object = object as? MySwiftProtocol { ... }` type of approach, but `Any.Type` cannot be the case.

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check the pure Swift code, you can do:

```
protocol MySwiftProtocol: AnyObject {
}

class MySwiftClass: MySwiftProtocol {
}

if MySwiftClass.self as? MySwiftProtocol.Type != nil {
    print("conforms")
} else {
    print("does not conform")
}
```

or more simply:

```
if MySwiftClass.self is MySwiftProtocol.Type {
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.  You nailed it.  I thought I have tried something similar, but something similar may not be able to nail it.

Answer (score -1):

The function `class_conformsToProtocol(_:_:)` is an Objective-C Runtime Library function so to use it the parameters provided must have a representation to Objective C.

Like when providing selector using `#selector()` asks and we have to provide `@objc` before the method declaration So that, that particular method can be represented in Objective-C.

You can find more about it in Apple Docs for [Objective-C Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime)

For checking if a class confirms a protocol you can try this:

```
protocol MySwiftProtocol: AnyObject {
}

class MySwiftClass: MySwiftProtocol {
}

if let mySwiftProtocol = MySwiftClass() as? MySwiftProtocol {
    //do stuff if confirms protocol
} else {
    //do stuff if doesn't confirm protocol
}
```